# What is the significance of weights for different roles in apache mesos

Tags: resources, distributed-computing, mesos

I would like to understand the concept of weights for different roles in mesos. I have given a weight of 2.0 for role1 and a weight of 5.0 for role2 and started spark framework in a mesos cluster and asked for the same amount of resources. I didn't see any changes in the way the resources were allocated for the two roles. So I wanted to know the importance of giving weights and show an example of resource reservation using weights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`TYPED_TEST(MasterAllocatorTest, RebalancedForUpdatedWeights)`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/3e2e018b8b3f526e8f7bcde5f479f7bca2b25f8d/src/tests/master_allocator_tests.cpp#L1587)

> This test ensures that resource allocation is correctly rebalanced according to the updated weights.

1. Start Mesos master.
2. Register three agents with the same resources.
3. Advance clock to force agents to register.
4. Total cluster resources (3 agents): `cpus=6, mem=3072`.
5. **Framework1** registers with `role1` which uses the default weight (1.0),
   and all resources will be offered to this framework since it is the only
   framework running so far.
6. **Framework2** registers with `role2` which also uses the default weight.
   It will not get any offers due to all resources having outstanding offers
   to framework1 when it registered.

   ```
   role1 share = 1 (cpus=6, mem=3072)
     Framework1 share = 1
   role2 share = 0
     Framework2 share = 0
   ```
7. Expect offer rescinded.
8. Update the weight of `role2` to 2.0. `updateWeights` will rescind all outstanding offers and the rescinded offer resources will only be available to the updated weights once
   another allocation is invoked.
9. Trigger a batch allocation.

   ```
   role1 share = 0.33 (cpus=2, mem=1024)
     Framework1 share = 1
   role2 share = 0.66 (cpus=4, mem=2048)
     Framework2 share = 1
   ```

Comment: I understood till step 9 to update the weights. After that, how to trigger a batch allocation?

Comment: You can change [allocation_interval](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/f1d0cdf1db2a28fa44f7aded0c3760636c0a51de/src/master/flags.cpp#L195)